# Why doesn't Neovim highlight newly created filetype?

Tags: syntax, neovim, potion

I installed [potion](https://github.com/perl11/potion) language on my Sierra system.
Also created two dirs:

```
$HOME/.vim/plugin/ftdetect  
  plus  
 $HOME/.vim/plugin/syntax
```

in which I put relevant filetype and syntax files, both named *potion.vim*.
Now, everything contained in the above mentioned *plugin* folder is supposed, and IS, so far, loaded at vim start, but the strange is that while filetype is recognized, syntax is not highlighted.
If i do:

```
:scriptnames
```

`$HOME/.vim/plugin/syntax/potion.vim` is there!

Also, I get syntax correctly loaded if I change *potion.vim* syntax file location, putting it, more directly, in a `$HOME/.vim/syntax` dir.

This last one I did not have so far and I wouldn't like to have to create, if there's no need.
In other words I would prefer having newly created plugins in the *plugin* directory, which should be there at this purpose, but for some reason it is not read on load.
At least part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct directories are `$HOME/.vim/ftdetect` and `$HOME/.vim/syntax`. Everything in `$HOME/.vim/plugin` will be sourced once at startup.

Using your directories, both files get sourced at startup and thus the syntax file gets applied to the first buffer only, not for all buffers setting the `potion` filetype.

When you put the syntax file into `$HOME/.vim/syntax/potion.vim`, then it will only get applied to buffers where the filetype is set to `potion`, which happens through the ftdetect file, which gets sourced no matter if it's in `$HOME/.vim/plugin/ftdetect` or `$HOME/.vim/ftdetect`, although the latter is the correct location.

See `:h ftdetect` and `:h plugin-details`.